# Xamarin forms multi language app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, localization, cross-platform, multilingual

im programming an application using xamarin forms 
And i want it to support 3 languages english freinch and Arabic 
How can i do so??
I can make it happen but only on the language ofdevice that the app is installed on for example if the emulator is using Arabic the app will display Arabic how can i make the user choose the language that he wants like a button or something can anyone help me please

I want it like a run time change in languages 
Like facebook u get to choose the language on the log in page and do not care about the device language

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take a look to this Xamarin Forms Sample.
It use RESX files.

[TodoLocalized](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoLocalized)

In your code, you could create a picker with Language description. For example

```
    List<string> _language = new List<string>();
    List<string> _languageDescription = new List<string> ();

    // Strings used to identify RESX
    _language.Add ("it");
    _language.Add ("en");

    // Strings visualized in picker
    _languageDescription.Add (AppResources.Italian);
    _languageDescription.Add (AppResources.English);

    // Fill the picker with _languageDescription values
    Picker _pickerLanguage = new Picker ();
    _pickerLanguage.Items.Clear ();
    foreach (string language in _languageDescription)
        _pickerLanguage.Items.Add (language);

    // When I select a language, I change the AppResource.Culture value
    _pickerLanguage.SelectedIndexChanged += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            if(_pickerLanguage.SelectedIndex >= 0){

                // Search the "_language" value that has the same index of selected _languageDescription value
                string myLanguage = _language [_languageDescription.FindIndex (o => o == _pickerLanguage.Items [_pickerLanguage.SelectedIndex])];

                // Modify the culture
                AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo (myLanguage);

            }
        };
```

Now you should refresh your page to see strings with new language

Hope this help